# C/C++ cool macro definitions?

Tags: c++, c, macros

Besides `__LINE__` and `__FILE__`, are there other useful pre-defined macros, like `__FUNCTION_NAME__`?

If not, but you know of other cool/useful defined macros (especially for debugging purposes), I'd love to hear about them.

Some have asked about platform: I'm using gcc/g++ on MacOSX.

Comment: That will be platform specific. Which platform are you on?

Comment: @dirkgently: `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` aren't platform specific.  And I think there are some more macro-like things (`__FUNCTION_NAME__` is not a macro) that are also part of the C and/or C++ standard.

Comment: @Omnifarious: Yes, I am aware of these. Since, he is looking for others, hence my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can find the following (descriptions from C99 draft, but they are available in C89 too I think):

- `__DATE__`: The date of translation of the preprocessing translation unit: a character
  string literal of the form "Mmm dd yyyy", where the names of the
  months are the same as those generated by the `asctime` function, and the
  first character of dd is a space character if the value is less than 10. If the
  date of translation is not available, an implementation-defined valid date
  shall be supplied.
- `__TIME__`: The time of translation of the preprocessing translation unit: a character
  string literal of the form "hh:mm:ss" as in the time generated by the
  `asctime` function. If the time of translation is not available, an
  implementation-defined valid time shall be supplied.

For the current function name, C99 defines `__func__`, but `__FUNCTION_NAME__` is not a standard macro.  In addition, `__func__` is not a macro, it's a reserved identifier (6.4.2.2p1):

> The identifier `__func__` shall be implicitly declared by the translator as if,
>   immediately following the opening brace of each function definition, the declaration
>
> `static const char __func__[] = "`*function-name*`";`
>
> appeared, where *function-name* is the name of the lexically-enclosing function.

If you're looking for something that's platform-specific: here's a list of [gcc's common predefined macros](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html).  I like `__COUNTER__`, which is a unique, sequential integer starting at 0. I think `__INCLUDE_LEVEL__`  is cool too, but not sure if I can think of a use for it yet :-).

Comment: `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` are available in C++, too.

Comment: `#include` recursion could be terminated by `__INCLUDE_LEVEL__`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Yeah I thought about that, but the compiler is going to detect infinite recursion for me anyway. Still, what you say has uses.

Answer (score 2):

This MSDN page lists the [complete set of predefined macros for MSVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(VS.80).aspx).

Personally, I think `__COUNTER__` is pretty cool.

Answer (score 2):

The specific one you're looking for is called `__func__`, but it's not exactly a macro, since it's meaning changes depending on where it's seen. It is useful, however, and does look like a macro.

My favorite macro at the moment is `__STDC_VERSION__` because it lets me do this:

```
#if !defined(__STDC_VERSION__) || __STDC_VERSION__ < 199901L
# define inline
# define register
# if __GNUC__ >= 2 || _MSC_VER >= 1300
#  define __func__ __FUNCTION__
# else
#  define __func__ "<unknown>"
# endif
#endif
```

Now you can use the C99 keywords `inline`, `register`, and `__func__` to declare things without having to worry about whether or not the compiler you're using supports that C99 functionality! In reality, the bit for `inline` is more complex since some compilers define `__inline` and other such silliness, but you get the general idea.

Also, a useful list of pre-defined macros for identifying compilers, operating systems, and architectures can be found [here](http://predef.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Chris, `__LINE__`'s meaning also changes depending upon where it is seen, so a name's expansion being dependent on where it is seen in the source doesn't necessarily imply it can't be a macro.  You're right about `__func__` not being a macro, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Common GCC [macros.](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, `__func__` is not a macro.  It's basically a name that's declared as `static const char * const __func__ = "function_name";` at the top of any function in which it is used.  And you should be using `__func__` instead of anything like `__FUNCTION_NAME__` because `__func__` is part of the C99 standard.

Comment: You are mistaken: The C99 construct is called `__func__`.

Comment: `__FUNCTION__` is a macro on MSVC.

Comment: Also, relating to my answer, if your compiler doesn't support C99, under GCC, if the `__GNUC__` macro is a value greater than 2 (or apparently if you're on MSVC) you can `#define __func__ __FUNCTION__` and get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to make single line conditions like.

```
#define ZZ_Slash_for_commenting_out /
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define D_B_O std::cerr
#else
#define D_B_O ZZ_Slash_for_commenting_out/
#endif
    D_B_O << "Your thing here" << endl;
```

Comment: If this works, it is a neat trick of generating a comment form macros!

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the regular pre-defined macros from gcc like this:

```
$ gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null
```

Of course this doesn't include special macros like:

```
__FILE__, __LINE__ and __FUNCTION__.
```